# Is it possible to load test an application hosted in linux server using jmeter?

Tags: linux, jmeter, load, load-testing

Am using Linux machine.I want to know that whether it is possible to load test an gaming application(includes HTTPs and websocket protocol) hosted on Linux server, using JMeter.

Comment: Yes, try and if you stuck write a relevant question, currently your question is too general

Comment: ok will try and post my queries regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want to run JMeter on Linux machine - it can be done because being a [pure Java application](https://jmeter.apache.org/) JMeter runs anywhere where Java runs. You can install Java on Linux using either your package manager or a 3rd-party tool like [SDKMAN!](https://sdkman.io/)
2. If you want to use JMeter to test application which runs on Linux it can be done as well, JMeter doesn't know anything about operating system of the application under test.

   - HTTP protocol can be covered using built-in [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler
   - WebSocket protocol can be covered by [WebSocket Samplers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers-a-practical-guide) (aren't shipped with JMeter, you will need to install them using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/))